# Parsing Weather Via Google

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, weather

I have been using ICB_WeatherConditions class to get local conditions for my app.  It has been working fine, but recently everything has been coming back null.  When I visit the site on my computer, it blocks it and warns that my computer may be sending automated queries.  Any ideas on if this is no longer a valid way to do this, or just a temporary error with server?

http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=%@, %@=zip code

Answer (score 0):

I guess you reached your quota. Check the Google Terms & Conditions for the usage of this service: as many Google services it probably allows the usage up to a limited quota (N requests per hours or similar), which is generally sufficient for general needs, but needs you to pay for the service if you really want to make much more requests in a small amount of time (to avoid their servers to be under a DDoS attacks especially from pirates that would spam their servers with tons of requests)

Comment: Just read that about a month ago Google quietly phased out Weather API.  Looks like I'll be looking for a different way to do this.

Comment: @user717452 did you find a way to do it? Please help! :(